# matrix multiplication in core.matrix

Tags: matrix, clojure

This seems like a silly question, but I can't figure this out after a bit of looking around, so I'll ask here.

How can I multiply a 3x2 matrix by a 2x3 matrix in core.matrix?  I must be misunderstanding something very basic.  Naively, I expected this to work and I thought core.matrix would do the underlying math for me.

```
(* (matrix [[1 0 -2] 
            [0 3 -1]]) 
   (matrix [[0   3] 
            [-2 -1] 
            [0   4]]))
```

I found this example via first hit on a google search http://www.purplemath.com/modules/mtrxmult.htm and the expected result is

```
[[ 0 -5]
 [-6 -7]]
```

Instead, I get:

```
RuntimeException Incompatible shapes, cannot broadcast [3 2] to [2 3] 
clojure.core.matrix.impl.persistent-vector/eval5013/fn--5014 
(persistent_vector.clj:152)
```

Thanks in advance.

p.s. my namespace looks just like the example from core.matrix

```
(ns xyz
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [* - + == /]) ; get from core.matrix
  (:use clojure.core.matrix)
  (:use clojure.core.matrix.operators)
  (:gen-class))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `*` matrix operator is an element-wise multiplication - that is, it forces the two operands to the same dimensions and produces a new matrix where the element at each position in the result is the product of the elements at that position in the operands.

I think you're looking for the `mmul` function from `clojure.core.matrix`.

Comment: Indeed you are correct.  Thanks!

(mmul (matrix [[1 0 -2] [0 3 -1]]) (matrix [[0 3] [-2 -1] [0 4]]))
==> [[0 -5] [-6 -7]]

Comment: One option to consider is to skip the step of pulling the matrix definition of `*` into your namespace, and just use `emul` along with `mmul`.  That way, there's no chance of forgetting what `*` means in your code, or wondering whether the variables multiplied hold numbers or matrices.  I feel that if I'm not defining functions that I want to to be able to apply to both matrices and numbers, then using overloaded arithmetic operators looks cool but could confuse readers (such as me) and lead to bugs.  This is a matter of personal preference, though.

Comment: @Mars I agree 100%, especially when it comes to functions defined in clojure.core. That code, when copied to a new namespace, might still compile but mean something totally different.

Comment: @Mars I completely agree, too.  I'll be using (:require [clojure.core.matrix :as mat]) instead of the ns above.  That ns was just what the example from github used.