# element wise multiplication of a matrix and a vector in core.matrix

Tags: matrix, clojure

How does one multiply a matrix and a vector element wise in core.matrix?

I am trying to find a core.matrix equivalent of the following octave code:

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8]
B = [2; 3]
A .* B

ans =
    2    4    6    8
   15   18   21   24
```

My guess would be that the following code should be equivalent:

```lisp
(let [A [[1 2 3 4]  
         [5 6 7 8]] 
      B [[2]        
         [3]]]      
  (* A B))
```

but it produces the following error:

```
RuntimeException: Incompatible shapes, cannot broadcast [2 1] to [2 4]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? Does this question help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982466/matrix-multiplication-in-core-matrix - I think the function mmul should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity here is that `core.matrix` is a bit stricter about broadcasting than octave.

In particular, broadcasting in `core.matrix` will only create new leading dimensions, and will normally not extend dimensions of length 1 to dimensions of arbitrary length.

EDIT: the reason for this is that `core.matrix` is actually an API that must support multiple underlying array implementations, so the default broadcasting is chosen to be something that can be implemented efficiently on most plausible underlying array types.

To solve your specific problem, you might consider:

- Ensuring the two matrices match exactly in shape
- Writing an explicit broadcast function that mimics octave behaviour

Comment: How painful would it be for a clojure novice, if I decided to try to extend the capacity of broadcast of core.matrix to cover this use-case? also is there a particular reason why core.matrix is stricter in it's approach ?

Answer (score 0):

`cannot broadcast [2 1] to [2 4]` means it cannot cast a 2*1 matrix to a 2*4 matrix.

Here in your code `(* A B)`, `*` operator means that: for each element in the matrix, find the element that is in the same position with another matrix and do the multiplication, then save the result in a new matrix. The `*` operator  is not meant to do matrix multiplication.

Comment: I'm not trying to do matrix multiplication here, i would like the B matrix to be broadcasted as a [2 4] matrix. As if each row was repeated 4 times such as `(mapv (fn [[x]] (repeat 4 x)) B)`